# Swagger Custom Attributes on the Operation

Tags: rest, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a unique requirement where DevOps is asking for an attribute in the swagger.json file they can use to key off of for some of their automations. The problem is that this attribute must be on the Operation/Path level. I tried using Tags but since that affects the Swagger UI grouping, the business has ruled against any changes that affect the UI.

The below snippet of json shows what I attempted first using Tags, but my needs would require an attribute on that same level that does not alter the UI at all. I tried playing with an Operation Filter but couldn't get a custom attribute injected to the json. Any help would be appreciated

```
"/company-profile": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Private"
        ],
        "custom attribute I need": "Private",
        "description": "Returns CompanyProfile",
        "blah blah blah"
        }
    }

//the swagger decorators that generated the above
[HttpGet("company-profile")]
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Admin", "Private" }, Description = "Returns CompanyProfile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyProfile() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this in .net core, we were able to extend the SwaggerOperation decorator, and then write a custom OperationFilter to consume that for adding our own properties to the swagger.json at the Operation/endpoint level

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SwaggerOperationExtendedAttribute : SwaggerOperationAttribute
{
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}

public class PublicFacingExtension : IOpenApiExtension
{
    private bool _isPublic;
    private string _serviceName;
    public PublicFacingExtension(bool isPublic, string serviceName)
    {
        _isPublic = isPublic;
        _serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    public void Write(IOpenApiWriter writer, OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("isPublic");
        writer.WriteValue(_isPublic);
        writer.WritePropertyName("serviceName");
        writer.WriteValue(_serviceName);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public class CheckPublicFacingOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        foreach (var item in descriptor.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes)
        {
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                CustomAttributeData validAttr = descriptor.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.AttributeType == typeof(SwaggerOperationExtendedAttribute));
                if (validAttr != null)
                {
                    CustomAttributeNamedArgument publicFacingArgument = validAttr.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault(e => e.MemberName == "IsPublic");
                    CustomAttributeNamedArgument serviceNameArgument = validAttr.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault(e => e.MemberName == "ServiceName");
                    if (publicFacingArgument.TypedValue.ArgumentType != null && !operation.Extensions.ContainsKey("x-public"))
                    {
                        operation.Extensions.Add("x-public", new PublicFacingExtension((bool)publicFacingArgument.TypedValue.Value, (string)serviceNameArgument.TypedValue.Value));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```